# Azure Devops CLI - restrict access

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-devops-rest-api

## Long story

I'm trying to setup Azure Devops (ADO) to allow access for clients - each would have its own Project, all within the same Organization.

Apparently ADO by default does not restrict the access to organization-wide information like listing all projects (even ones you are not member of) or all users (even these you have no project in common with). This is considered an issue, as the project names would expose to each client which other clients are there, same with users.

To tackle this a feature has been developed by Microsoft 2 years ago, "Limit user visibility and collaboration to specific projects". [Here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/limit-user-visibility-and-collaboration-to-specific-projects/) a blog post on this.

HOWEVER, this feature works only on the presentation layer...

> Note that the current restrictions are on the user interface only; users will still be able to use the REST APIs to produce or construe the restricted data.

I did check the API and it seems this should be safe as for all authentication methods you need some kind of token which only an "admin" can generate on ADO.

## Issue

The problem is that when using the Azure CLI including the azure-devops extension I still can see the list of all users in the organization. This means for me the client would see all users of my other clients too, which is suboptimal.

Here the CLI command I use to display the list of users:

```
az devops user list -o table
```

In general this behavior does match [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-devops-user-list)

> List users in an organization

Still, is there any way to restrict this to the projects you're member of? Maybe some security groups that would restrict the returned list of users? Or maybe it is even possible to restrict the usage of the CLI at all?

Comment: I guess, az CLI is just calling an API. And according to documentation there is no such restriction with an organization as you want. Organizations are meant for collaboration but you want isolation.

Maybe you shouldn't use single organization for that ‍♂️

Comment: I don't think it's that black or white with collaboration / isolation - I do want to collaborate with the clients, however I also want to have control over what information I'm sharing.
I have considered setting up each client with an own organization, but this approach disregards any collaboration capabilities of ADO, which actually make the case to use ADO in the first place. Setting up new organizations for each client comes with a lot of additional maintenance - instead of two clicks for a new project you need to setup users, billing information, create custom processes from scratch etc.